# How to get facebook comments of ads posts using Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, post, facebook-graph-api, ads

I am the admin of my companies Facebook page. I'm trying to get all the ads for the Facebook page using the Graph API. The access token that I use has the following permissions:

- read_insights
- manage_pages
- ads_read
- ads_managment
- ...

How can I get the comments below the ads posts?

This is what I tried using Graph API:

```
my_page_ID/ads_posts
```

[image]

What I get is this:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "created_time": "2020-03-26T14:42:38+0000",
      "message": "We have the best price. Please come to us!",
      "id": "4353425346_5634563463622263"
    },
    {
      "created_time": "2020-03-26T12:28:35+0000",
      "message": "This is some add",
      "id": "65464567_687456456"
    },
    {
      "created_time": "2020-03-26T12:19:34+0000",
      "message": "This is the message of the ad.",
      "id": "123456789_463456534623"
    },
    {
      "created_time": "2020-03-20T08:06:44+0000",
      "id": "34534588605_358563733107"
    },
    {
      "created_time": "2020-03-20T08:06:44+0000",
      "id": "388533217888605_3586754538066441"
    },
    {
      "created_time": "2020-03-20T08:06:44+0000",
      "id": "34353417888605_5844534530"
    },
    {
      "created_time": "2020-03-20T08:06:44+0000",
      "id": "38854535405_230852376563421"
    },
    {
      "created_time": "2020-03-20T08:06:18+0000",
      "id": "382342345605_358677843899"
```

**What I do not understand:**

- Why are most fields empty? Am I doint sth. wrong? Do I need more permissions?
- How can I retriev **all** ads posts and not just a few?
- How can I retriev the user comments below these posts?

Hope you can help me with this.

Comment: _“Why are most fields empty?”_ - because you didn’t ask for _any_, so you get only a very small set of default fields back.

Comment: Thank you very much! What can I do to get all ads posts? Can you please give a short example or reference a source which explains it?

Comment: The `limit` parameter allows you to specify how many items you want to get back, but there is a limit _to_ the limit you can specify, usually something like 25 or 100, depends on the specific endpoint. If you need to get more data than that, you will have to use pagination, that is explained in the documentation on basic Graph API usage, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#paging

Comment: What is the correct way to specifiy the limit? Itried many different ways, e.g. ```my_page_id/ads_posts.limit(25)```. The API always returns an error

Comment: With such basics requests, you specify it as a GET parameter - `my_page_id/ads_posts?limit=25`. The `.limit()` syntax only comes into play when _field expansion_ syntax gets used.

Comment: Thank you! Good news: when I do ```my_page_id/ads_posts?limit=25```, I get no error returned anymore. Bad news: I get the same empty fields as in the beginning. Maybe I need more permissions to see the data?

Comment: `limit` is for the number of ads_posts you want to get from this endpoint; the _fields_ you want, you still need to ask for. Go check the documentation I referred to, this is explained on the same page.

Comment: Great, I just discovered that all the empty fields are ads that have no text (therefore no field ```message```). The ads only show figures or videos. This is why most parts of my problems are solved. Can you please explain me, how I can get the comments below the ad? Not really explained from your reference that you have linked. I tried ```my_page_id/ads_posts?fields=comments``` but I get empty fields back

Comment: Please forget what I said in the previous post. Just discovered that all the empty ads have not comments which is why they are empty :-) I need to spend some time investigating this

Comment: Thank you very much. With your help I was able to selve all problems :-)

Comment: @PParker did you ever resolve the issue of comments on the ads? I'm trying to get all comments on ads posted (including dark posts).  I've tried the below suggestion of /{page-id}/ads_posts?include_inline_create=true which does show a list of ids (Ad ids) some of which are empty, but some have messages attached, but if i try to get comments on the ad ids with messages i always get back an empty set, even though i can see comments on these ads on facebook?

Answer (score 2):

Easy peasy!

```
/{page-id}/ads_posts?include_inline_create=true
```

Includes all Ads Posts (Dark Posts)